# Jar is running when embedded as applet in webpage but is not running when using jnlp method

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, jnlp, japplet

I have to embed a  class of a jar file in a webpage

The functionality works fine when using the java applet tag but because of security issues from client computers , had to look for an alternative.

Tried writing a jnlp file for the jar and using deployjava.runapplet in webpage to run the same.
But this displays a blank grey screen and shows no error in java console.

How can I debug my issue?

P.S : I did not  sign any of the jar files

Comment: using word "internet protocol" because this is my first post and this website is not allowing me to write short form. The same is the case for my default tomcat link as this website is not allowing me to write full form of the word lh.So imagine lh in the place of x.x.x.x for default tomcat link

Comment: you should do the following checks:
1) is network/tomcat issue? 
  ---> try to wget the jar file from tomcat using that url
if no, it is a client issue (i.e.: security problem?)
  ---> check what happen on the java console: it should say what is downloading, from where and if and why there are problems

Comment: @Dan M 1.There is no firewall issue from client side and the  url is not working even from hosrt machine 
2.I will try java console and inform the observations

Comment: Java console showing no errors

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, but do check if you are using absolute URL in your HTML, this sometime causes the behaviour you have described.

Comment: I used an absolute url. This is my first post and thus not able to post complete link

Comment: Use relative URL, when you are accessing x.x.x.x as the server, the browser is trying to get the JNLP from localhost (assuming you have used http://localhost:8080/....), if you have used absolute URL in the HTML, change it to /test/JNLP_name, should work, check